# CSS for dynamic inserted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently I'm working on a website where I'd like to show some toolstips for specific DIV elements. My weapon of choice is [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).

So when I use `$(".toolTipMe").tooltip();` it works quite nice. As soon as I hover the element a new DIV appears in the DOM:

```
<div class="tooltip" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 313.65px; left: 798.5px;">foo</div>
```

However the design is done by our very own css-monster (you should this this guy!) and he's using a a lot of z-indexes so the .tooltip-DIV is behind the other elements.

Now the question:
The following code in our .css File is not having any effect:

```
.tooltip{
    z-index: 9001;
}
```

In fact the attribute is not even showing up when debugging the website. But the following will work:

```
$(".toolTipMe").tooltip({
  onShow: function(){
    $(this).css("z-index","9001");
  }
});
```

I'm not sure how CSS Rules are applied for dynamic inserted DOM Elements but what I really detest in the current workaround is the mixture of functionality and style. Any chance to clean up this mess? :C

Comment: In Chrome or Firebug you can check what attributes an element has. Even dynamic ones. Maybe there is something wrong with the selector?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can add a tooltip without the need of JS (or jQuery for that matter)! Cf. http://bramvanroy.be/ hover over one of the links. This is done with ONLY css(3). This may solve some of the hard times you're getting and it's easy to implement.

Comment: Like @Remy says, maybe there's something wrong with the selector. In your CSS you use `.tooltip` but in your JS you use `.ui_day`...

Comment: Well the selectors are ok because the DIV with the tooltip is showing up. It's merely behind other elements. When using Firebug I see no z-index attribute using plain CSS. However when setting it in Firebug or via JS it works.

Comment: Right Alex, I changed the names for posting :)

Comment: Add some color to your css tooltip definition. If the color is there, but the z-index not, we at least know that the selector works for sure.

Comment: Yes colours, width, height etc. work. It seems Rui did a good guess with !important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with jquery tools, but if your z-index is not working you must need a `!important` tag or making it `position:relative` or `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

In jquery tools tooltip you need to specify the `z-index` inside the tooltip constructor like:

$(".toolTipMe").tooltip({ z-index: '9001'});

I'm not sure if it is `z-index` or `zindex`.. check it out